# Scrape Table With Merge Header

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

i have problem right now about scraping header table (merged) using cheerio nodejs, which mean this is im using for grouping or something. im able to scrap without header. here a lil bit
[Screenshot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODrQN.jpg)

and html code for table or fiddle for html table [here](https://jsfiddle.net/coffeelake99/c4ny0usL/13/):

```
 <div class="wrap">
   <table class="tbl">
     <tr class="head">
       <td colspan="6" style="background-color:#656968">Monday</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="head">
       <td class="center" width="20%">Code</td>
       <td class="center" width="40%">Title</td>
       <td class="center" width="20%">Price</td>
       <td class="center last" width="20%">Status</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="td1">
       <td class="center">Code 1</td>
       <td class="center">Name 1</td>
       <td class="center">1.234</td>
       <td class="center last">
         <span class="green">Closed</span>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   <table class="tbl">
     <tr class="head">
       <td colspan="6" style="background-color:#656968">Tuesday</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="head">
       <td class="center" width="20%">Code</td>
       <td class="center" width="40%">Title</td>
       <td class="center" width="20%">Price</td>
       <td class="center last" width="20%">Status</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="td1">
       <td class="center">Code 1</td>
       <td class="center">Name 1</td>
       <td class="center">1.234</td>
       <td class="center last">
         <span class="green">Closed</span>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   <table class="tbl">
     <tr class="head">
       <td colspan="6" style="background-color:#656968">Wednesday</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="head">
       <td class="center" width="20%">Code</td>
       <td class="center" width="40%">Title</td>
       <td class="center" width="20%">Price</td>
       <td class="center last" width="20%">Status</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="td1">
       <td class="center">Code 1</td>
       <td class="center">Name 1</td>
       <td class="center">1.234</td>
       <td class="center last">
         <span class="green">Closed</span>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="td2">
       <td class="center">Code 1</td>
       <td class="center">Name 1</td>
       <td class="center">1.234</td>
       <td class="center last">
         <span class="green">Closed</span>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="td1">
       <td class="center">Code 1</td>
       <td class="center">Name 1</td>
       <td class="center">1.234</td>
       <td class="center last">
         <span class="green">Closed</span>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   <table class="tbl">
     <tr class="head">
       <td colspan="6" style="background-color:#656968">Thursday</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="head">
       <td class="center" width="20%">Code</td>
       <td class="center" width="40%">Title</td>
       <td class="center" width="20%">Price</td>
       <td class="center last" width="20%">Status</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="td1">
       <td class="center">Code 1</td>
       <td class="center">Name 1</td>
       <td class="center">1.234</td>
       <td class="center last">
         <span class="green">Closed</span>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
```

here my cheerio :

```
   const sel = "tr.td1, tr.td2";
$(sel).each(function (i, e) {

  $(this).find("td:first").each(function (i, e) {
    code.push({
      code: $(this).text().trim()
    })
  });
  $(this).find("td:eq(1)").each(function (i, e) {
    title.push({
      title: $(this).text().trim()
    })
  });
  $(this).find("td:eq(2)").each(function (i, e) {
    price.push({
      price: $(this).text().trim()
    })
  });
  $(this).find("td:eq(3)").each(function (i, e) {
    status.push({
      status: $(this).text().trim()
    })
  });
let merged = [];
for (var i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
  merged.push({
    ...code[i],
    ...title[i],
    ...price[i],
    ...status[i]
  })
}
```

and yes, im able to gettin array as my hope, looks like

```
[
  {
    "code": "Code 1",
    "title": "Name 1",
    "price": "1.234",
    "status": "Closed",
  },
 {
    "code": "Code 1",
    "title": "Name 1",
    "price": "1.234",
    "status": "Closed",
  },
 {
    "code": "Code 1",
    "title": "Name 1",
    "price": "1.234",
    "status": "Closed",
  }
]
```

and what i need is, inside json i have day value, which is position is at header merged, final result i need looks like this

```
[
  {
    "code": "Code 1",
    "title": "Name 1",
    "price": "1.234",
    "status": "Closed",
    "group": "Monday"

  },
 {
    "code": "Code 1",
    "title": "Name 1",
    "price": "1.234",
    "status": "Closed",
    "group": "Monday"
  },
 {
    "code": "Code 1",
    "title": "Name 1",
    "price": "1.234",
    "status": "Closed",
    "group": "Monday"
  },
      {
    "code": "Code 1",
    "title": "Name 1",
    "price": "1.234",
    "status": "Closed",
    "group": "Tuesday"

  },
 {
    "code": "Code 1",
    "title": "Name 1",
    "price": "1.234",
    "status": "Closed",
    "group": "Tuesday"
  },
 {
    "code": "Code 1",
    "title": "Name 1",
    "price": "1.234",
    "status": "Closed",
    "group": "Tuesday"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than starting at the bottom and trying to work back up to the parent groups, I'd loop over the parents, then grab their children with the needed grouping info at hand. You can then create a nested structure organized by group, or flatten it out to the result you expect:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `<Your HTML from the question>`;
const headers = ["code", "title", "price", "status"];
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const data = [...$(".tbl")].flatMap(table =>
  [...$(table).find(".td1, td2")].map(row => ({
    ...Object.fromEntries([...$(row).find("td")].map((e, i) =>
      [headers[i], $(e).text().trim()]
    )),
    group: $(table).find(".head").first().text().trim(),
  }))
);
console.log(data);
```